# How to get and display student’s name in textbox when his/her ID is entered in another textbox

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a form:

```
<from method="post">
  Student ID: <input type="text" id="std_id"/>
  Student Name: <input type="text" id="std_name"/>
  Class: <input type="text" id="class"/>

  <input type="submit" name="submit_form"/>
</form>
```

What I want: when I type student’s ID in textbox his/her name & class should be fetched from database and should be automatically displayed in `std_name` textbox without using a submit button.

The name of the table in database is `student_info`. I have already created a connection file in a separate php page `connection.php`.

So can someone help me? This is the second time I ask the same question because I couldn’t get a proper answer in my first question. Thanks.

<--------------------------------------------------------->

I did the following but nothing appears in name textbox. Here is the code what I did:

On Main Page:

```
<script>
  $("#std_id").on('input propertychange', function(){

    $.post('get_data.php', { std_id:$("#std_id").val() }).done(function(data){

        $("#std_name").val(data.std_name);

    });
  });
 </script>
```

On get_data.php

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');

if (isset($_POST['std_id'])) {


    $select = mysql_query("SELECT * from student_timetable, student_info 
               WHERE student_timetable.std_id='".$_POST['std_id']."'
               AND student_timetable.std_id = student_info");

    $row=mysql_fetch_array($select);

    $json_arr[] = array('std_name' => $row['std_name']);

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json_arr);
} 

?>
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript/jQuery for this already?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @wumm, can you add some  AJAX "to study" link in your hard comment? Then the comment would be more balanced.

Comment: And jquery is just a library makes your life easier. All you (really) need is javascript and async javascript.

Comment: You have `get_data.php` and `get_date.php` mixed up in the code. Also, there's no need for `[]` in `$json_arr[]`

Comment: Try replacing `student_timetable.std_id='".$_POST['std_id']."'` with `student_timetable.std_id=$_POST['std_id']` (if std_id is supposed to be a whole number (INT)).

Comment: Also, what you could do is (just for testing purpose), replace `$_POST['std_id']` in *get_data.php* with `$_GET['std_id']` and just open *get_data.php?std_id=N* and replace *N* with a number that should give a result. This, just to make sure the database fetching part works.

Comment: It was actually get_data.php I mistakenly wrote it get_date.php. I've remove the [] braces from $json_arr variable but it doesn't work yet. any suggestion plz.

Comment: @user3274862 did you test the database fetching part as I suggested?

Comment: I opened http://localhost/IPSAC/get_data.php?std_id=1 and it gave me the correct result by using his name "{"name":"Hamid Khan"}" but it is not showing it on the textbox in the main page.

Comment: Try replacing: `$("#std_name").val(data.std_name);

    });` with `$("#std_name").val(data.std_name);

    }, "json");`

Comment: I replaced it with $("#std_name").val(data.std_name); }, "json"); but it shows an error.

Comment: @user3274862 What error?

Comment: It says a syntax error, I couldn't find it out <script>
  $("#std_id").on('input propertychange', function(){

    $.post('get_data.php', { std_id:$("#std_id").val() }).done(function(data){

        
  $("#std_name").val(data.std_name); }, "json");

    });
  });
</script>

Comment: Replace the JS code you posted with `<script>$("#std_id").on('input propertychange', function () {
    $.post('get_data.php', {
        std_id: $("#std_id").val()
    }).done(function (data) {
        $("#std_name").val(data.std_name);
    }, "json");
});</script>`

Comment: I replaced the code No more error but doesn't show the name in textbox.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47595/discussion-between-daniel-lisik-and-user3274862)

Answer (score 1):

On your main page:

```
$("#std_id").on('input propertychange', function(){

    $.post('get_data.php', { std_id:$("#std_id").val() }).done(function(data){

        $("#std_name").val(data.std_name);
        $("#class").val(data.class);

    });

});
```

get_data.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['std_id'])) {


    // Fetch data from DB with post value
    // While fetching,  push values to json array, like: 
    // $json_arr[] = array('std_name' => $row['std_name'], 'class' => $row['class']);

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json_arr);
} 

?>
```

Comment: I did it on the same way but it doesn't work. I've copied the code in above showing you how I did it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi You really have to consider about learning AJAX. If you want to find solution via Jquery Here you go.

HTML:

```
<from method="post">
  Student ID: <input type="text" id="std_id"/>
  Student Name: <input type="text" id="std_name"/>
  Class: <input type="text" id="class"/>

  <input type="submit" name="submit_form"/>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function{
   $.post("connection.php",{},function(result}{
      var getJSON = JSON.parse(result);
       $("#std_name").val(getJSON.StudentName);
        $("#class").val(getJSON.class);
    });
});
```

Import JQUERY and use ready function to fetch on first time.

PHP:

```
<?php
   $result[0]['StudentName']='abc';
   $result[0]['class']='Class 5';  
   echo JSON.decode($result);
?>
```

It's very sample PHP you can expand it how ever you want. While fetching from PHP.

Comment: Okay here is the thing you are missing  '<script>
  $("#std_id").on('input propertychange', function(){

    $.post('get_data.php', { std_id:$("#std_id").val() }).done(function(data){
         var getJSON = JSON.parse(data);
        $("#std_name").val(getJSON.std_name);

    });
  });
 </script>'

Comment: I replaced it with your js code but it doesn't work. What is the reason?

Comment: Can You replace your php like $json_arr[0]['std_name'] = $row['std_name']; and use the method same in jquery

Comment: I did still no name in textbox. Do I need to specify onpropertychange in name textbox in here: <input type="text" id="std_name"/>??

Comment: can you check what the result it's coming in jquery ready function.$.post("connection.php",{},function(result}{ after this console.log(result) and send it across.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax()

Use this jquery function.. study about that

Answer (score 0):

Since jquery is a client side language it cannot connect to the php directly. You can accomplish this task using Ajax and JSON together or creating your own web service.

Ajax: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ 
JSON: http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you should use AJAX. Consider using jQuery for that.
The workflow is as follows:

- Prepare a PHP file which would echo a student's name based on the Id it receives from the form;
- Add an event listener to your Id field (for example, onBlur — so you'll get your name when you bring the focus out of the Id field);
- Pass the Id value to your PHP file that would echo the name;
- Add the result gotten from the PHP file to your Name field.

Answer (score 0):

Get jquery library (//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js)

Make an ajax request to connection.php (I suppose it gets a studentID as parameter and returns the rest)

On response arrival (success parameter of $.ajax) get the response and edit those two input elements.

P.S. You won't get a proper answer of this because it's a whole process. You need a lesson not just help because you are stuck somewhere.